# XML Programming C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to extract the data from the XML file and use this data to go thorough the database tables and get further more data, appending the new table data to the previous XML file .Finally displaying the XML file in Web application.

Please let me know if any one has gone through same process with some sample ideas and code.

My application is in .NET & C#

Thanks,

Comment: If you're asking whether anybody has ever used XML and a DB in a web app, the answer is yes.  You will get better answers if you can be more specific.

Comment: How far have you got, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 1):

You should use LINQ to XML, it can do all of this, including parsing XML and creating new XML documents.

For more information and code samples check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx